# How to resolve "Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator" using watir

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webdriver, watir

I keeps on getting this error when i invoke the browser with below line of code.Please comment if there is any solution to disable this popup

```
@browser=Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, :switches => %w[--disable-extensions --disable-infobars])
```

[image]

Comment: I am using a chrome driver with version 2.32.498550

Comment: Remove that extension, it's probably malware. Run Chrome cleanup tool.

Comment: I tried this but its not working.I can see everytime when chrome starts this scoped_dir* file is getting created in temp.I changed the chrome driver to 2.35 and google chrome browser v64.0 but no luck.

Comment: is there any way to resolve this issue.I am struggling with this for the past 3 days.?